# ActivityManager.forceStopPackage() from Task Manager

Tags: android

This is my first time posting here. I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but I don't seem to find other more appropriate places. Here's my question anyways.

I understand that the API `ActivityManager.forceStopPackage()` is an internal one and can be called only from system process. However, it puzzles me that the built-in Task Manager app (with package name `com.motorola.PerformanceManager`) on my **motorola atrix** phone can directly call it without being a system process. There are two things that I verified.

First, it is non-system process from `ps` command:

```
app_64 13681 1379 170788 29820 ffffffff 00000000 S com.motorola.PerformanceManager
```

Second, it indeed calls the `ActivityManager.forceStopPackage()` API from its odex file (decompiled into smali, then into dex, and then into java). From the smali code, it is already clear that it calls this API.

I also checked its `AndroidManifest.xml` file which seems nothing special to me (the forum mistakenly recognizes the content as URLs and prevents me from posting them).

The manifest file does include the `android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES` permission which is supposed to be a system one. A non-system app will still get permission denial error even with this permission. I tried using reflection to access this API with `android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES` permission but still get the runtime error.

Now, how can the built-in Task Manager app call the internal API without being a system process. 
One possibility is that the app is signed with the same platform private key. However, I'm not sure how I can verify that. Further, it is still supposed to be a system process with additional descriptions in the manifest file.

Hope someone can answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: i have the same issue like:java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
  forceStopPackage() from pid=20914, uid=10073 requires android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES ,,,can you please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES" permission is protected by the platform signature.

If you have Android source code then check the declaration of the permission:

/frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
    <permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"
...
```

You can see its protection level is signature, then check the SDK documentation for the explaination:

"android:protectionLevel"

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel

"signature...A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission. If the certificates match, the system automatically grants the permission without notifying the user or asking for the user's explicit approval"

The permission is declared by the framework-res which is signed by the platform signature, so the application that wants to use the permission shall also be signed with the same signature.

/frameworks/base/core/res/Android.mk

```
...
     LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := framework-res
     LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
...
```

Regards

Ziteng Chen

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the right answer. However, I am still not sure how I can verify that the app is indeed signed with the platform key. According to the app's manifest file, the permission is simply written as <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES" /> (nowhere is the protectionLevel mentioned in the manifest file). This is somewhat contradicting to what we understand?

Comment: All the .apk files shall be signed but you may not aware of it because the Eclipse ADT has done it for you. Follow the guide to sign apk by your own keys:

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard

If you have the Android source then you can find the Android debug certificates in /build/target/product/security folder, but phone manufactures will normally replace the certificates by their own live certificates which are confidential and will never be revealed to you and me, so I'm afraid you can not get for example the platform certificate of a Motorola phone.

Comment: Thanks again. Just to double check if I understand this correctly. I understand every .apk file is signed with a certificate. But the thing is that according to the spec, isn't the FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES permission supposed to have a line of "android:protectionLevel="signature" in the manifest file? Are you saying this is not really necessary (the built-in task manager app does not have this line at all)? I'll mark your response as answer after you confirmed my understanding.

Comment: android:protectionLevel is a property of the <permission> tag which is used to define a permission.
Apps use <uses-permission> tag to declare that they need the permission.