# How to remove applications run in background?

Tags: android, background

I have an application which lists all installed applications and launch them on item click.Now I updated it with blocking some applications like Settings, android market place etc...For this I used a service which stops only when exiting from my application.This service continuously checke for currently running applications.If it is a blocked one then show a new activity like this.

```
private void currentlyRunningApps() {
    List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks = ((ActivityManager) getApplicationContext() .getSystemService("activity")).getRunningTasks(1);
    if (runningTasks != null && !runningTasks.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < runningTasks.size(); i++) {
            RunningTaskInfo runningtaskinfo = (RunningTaskInfo) runningTasks .get(i);
            String packageName = runningtaskinfo.topActivity.getPackageName();
            if(checkBlackListedTask(runningtaskinfo)) {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                     // show action not allowed activity 
                    }
                });
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine.But  when exiting from my application the blocked applications stayed in background.I tried `killBackgroundProcesses` and `restartPackage` method.But they won't work.

```
 Method forceStopPackage = am.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("forceStopPackage", String.class);     
             forceStopPackage.setAccessible(true);     
             forceStopPackage.invoke(am,package name);
```

This throws null pointer exception

How can i close these blocked application before showing `'action not allowed'` activity ?

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcess()** allows you to kill processes that are in the background and not visible to the user. This is to prevent you to disrupt execution of other apps.

Only system app (apps that are in /system/app) can forcestop other apps. Basically we need **“android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES”** permission to do so. However it is protected by the platform signature. That’s why Samsung has a TaskManager that can kill apps, while we developers cannot. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6578213/1697047) for more info

Comment: do u check the link which i have mentioned.

Comment: Yes i added  <permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" /> to manifest

Comment: can you able to post your log cat

Comment: When i tried to print this exception is show only null.  forceStopPackage.invoke(activityManager, package name) throws this exception.