# Android Permission Denial: forceStopPackage()

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I am try to kill another application using **forceStopPackage()**. But my application shows runtime error.

**Error** :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: forceStopPackage() from pid=10377, uid=10200 requires android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES
```

In my manifest file i added the following permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />

    <permission
        android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" />
```

**Code** :

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) 
         context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
Method forceStopPackage = am.getClass().
          getDeclaredMethod("forceStopPackage", String.class);  
    forceStopPackage.setAccessible(true);  
    forceStopPackage.invoke(am, packageName);
```

How to solve the problem.

Comment: have u try in code with finish();

Comment: By disabling the **ProtectedPermission** in the properties of your Project, you can generate the **apk**

Comment: @Prasanth S  I have a doubt..i am getting the same issue..could you please help me to solve the issue..

Comment: Did you check this ? : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6578213/1405983

Answer (score 7):

I know this is ab old thread but i wanted to make sure engineers visiting this thread has latest information.

android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES  is signature | priviliged permission hence it needs to go in to system partition under priv-app. So whoever wants to have this permission in their app have to work with respective OEM to pre-load them on to priv-app.

Starting from Android O:  This permission along with App name needs to be declared in one of the permission xml

privapp-permissions-platform.xml   –  AOSP Apps
privapp-permissions-google.xml – Google Apps
privapp-permissions-.xml – OEM/ODM, OEM Associated  and others

```
<privapp-permissions package="com.abc.android.xyz">
<permission name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"/>
</privapp-permissions>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you know if since Android O, the entry inside privapp-permissions-xx.xml is enough to get the permission granted, or is placing the app into /system/priv-app/ still required?

Comment: privapp-permission-xxx.xml is applicable for those apps that gets into /system/priv-app/.  So it is not enough to get permission placed in \etc\permission\ folder   
 For more information : https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist

Comment: @siva `So whoever wants to have this permission in their app have to work with respective OEM to pre-load them on to priv-app` is not true if you are working on creating your own ROM, you can bundle the application inside `/system/apps` and your app will get the system permissions.
Its a different ballgame if you want to get your application to the whole world, then your statement is true.

Comment: @Nikhil Kumar Private ROM is irrelevant for this discussion IMO and not helpful for the App developers targeting main stream. You can do N number of things with own ROM literally slay all Android O restrictions. Also Apps in /system/app will not have Priviliged permission but only System permissions.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml like below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"></uses-permission>
```

Make sure only if your app is signed with system key os will allow to stop other apps.

Comment: how to make it signed

Comment: @RohitTigga take a look -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature