# Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: forceStopPackage() from pid=xxx, uid=xxx requires android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES

Tags: android, kotlin, methods, permissions, signature

im struggling when using the method to force stop another running application in my app. I already see another thread in StackOverflow that my app need signed apk to run the force stop method. However, i already build and run in my android but it still says like below:
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: forceStopPackage() from pid=xxx, uid=xxx requires android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES
This is my code:

```
val am = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
val forceStopPackage: Method = am.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("forceStopPackage", String::class.java)
forceStopPackage.isAccessible = true
forceStopPackage.invoke(am, radPackage) //radPackage is active running app
```

Here is the option to build signed app:
[image]

And here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.xxx.xxx">



    <permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

</manifest>
```

Ill try running the app in real device with version Android P (API 28).

Comment: That's a privileged permission - check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717708/android-permission-denial-forcestoppackage)

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to be a priv-app to acquire the `android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES` permission.

You need to have your app in
`/system/priv-app/com.yourapp.package/` directory to acquire the required permission.

You can use these commands for testing purpose

```
$ adb root
$ adb remount
$ adb shell mkdir /system/priv-app/com.yourapp.package/
$ adb push </path/to/apk> /system/priv-app/com.yourapp.package/
$ adb reboot
```

But you may have to work with the ODM to make your app a priv-app in actual customer scenarios.